# How to install pkg in a non-standard location? (OS X)

Tags: macos, installation, osx-lion, python, python-gui

In brief, my question is this:

***How can I install an OS X framework from a *.pkg file somewhere other than under `/Library/Frameworks` (or `/System/Library/Frameworks`)?***

---

**Background**

I want to install a version of Python 2.7.3 that lives under `$HOME/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and `$HOME/python`.

My goal here is to have a version of Python that is as independent as possible from the Python that comes with OS X Lion.

Among the problems I am trying to avoid by doing this is the [buggy Tk framework](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk) that comes with the latest versions of OS X.

Therefore, a key sub-goal here is to install new Tcl and Tk frameworks, separate from the system-supplied ones.  The ones I want to install come from [ActiveState ("Mac OS X (10.5+, x86_64/x86)")](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads), in the form of a *.pkg file.

When I click on this file, I get presented with the usual "wizard"-like sequence of steps ("Introduction", "License", etc.).  At no point during this sequence I am offered the opportunity to choose a different installation location for these frameworks before I reach the choice of clicking on the <kbd>INSTALL</kbd> button.<sup>1</sup>

I suspect that if I click on this button, the installed files will go under `/Library/Frameworks` (or possibly under `/System/Library/Frameworks`), which is what I'm trying to avoid.  (Indeed, when I click on <kbd>INSTALL</kbd>, I'm immediately presented with an password-entry dialog, which is a pretty good indication that the installation will put files somewhere under `/Library` or `/System`.)

Therefore I'm looking for an alternative way to perform this installation that will allow me to *explicitly set* the destination folder for the installed files.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Yes, the installer allows me choose a different volume for the installation, but it does not let me specify, e.g., `$HOME/Library/Frameworks` as the destination for the installed files.</sub>

Comment: If you want a version as independent as possible, compile it manually in `/usr/local`, for example.

Comment: @slhck: I need instructions for how to do that; the ActiveState website does not offer a source version of the package.  Maybe the source code is contained inside the *.pkg archive, but I don't know how to extract it, etc.

Comment: You can get the sources and compile them yourself, e.g. from [here](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2), or with [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) (which automatically compiles it for you into `/usr/local`). But this is really just Python—no idea about Tcl/Tk.